# I can only access NodeJS server locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, port, digital-ocean

My server's hosted at DigitalOcean (it's a droplet) and basically, I cannot access my NodeJS app via Internet, only server-side. It's running on port 9000, I've allowed traffic to the port via ufw and iptables, no luck. When I run curl || wget while SSH-ed to the server, I get a normal response as if everything's in order. But when I try to access the server from an another machine, I just get timed out because the server returns nothing. I've heard DigitalOcean sometimes disable connections to all ports except ssh,www and ssl, but I think I've successfully 'opened' them. Any suggestions?

[image: When I run <code>netstat -tulp | grep LISTEN</code> I get the following:]

This is what I get when I run `netstat -tulp | grep LISTEN`

Comment: Have you checked out their community first? I quickly checked and found a number of posts related to this kind of problem.  It seems that the answer may be solved their by their community members already.  Also, have you checked your own network to ensure your side is not blocking the requests?

Comment: I have, extensively.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  It sometimes helps to know what has / has not been tried, and for providers, sometimes their other community members have run into similar issues, and already have good answers.

Comment: Don't mention it. It's really bothering me since everything I check is in order. I guess I'm not checking everything :D

Comment: How did you open those ports? Port 9000 is a non-standard port, so if you have opened the "www" port, you most likely had port 80 (which is the standard port for www/HTTP) opened. FWIW, make sure that your MongoDB port (27017) remains closed from the outside world, because your server seems to be exposing it.

Comment: Mongo was open to connections on purpose, at the time I had no NodeJS app running but I had to populate the database from multiple sources. Thanks for the concern tho.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my dashboard was all messed up when it comes to ports, which I forgot to check, of course, so opening them directly on the server gave no results whatsoever.